# Workflow question for inspections

Tags: 2013

It’s been a while since I’ve done a workflow and I’m trying to figure out the best process to use. [image]

I’ve included the above flow chart to try and explain what I’m doing. Basically a request comes in for an inspection of a location. I want to be able to assign an inspector that will then get an email notifying them that they have an inspection request scheduled. Once they complete the inspection, I would like them to have the ability to enter notes of their inspection, then it be routed to a senior inspector for review. Email notification would be needed. The SR can then review and approve with any comments so it is then routed to the manager. Or deny then routed back to the inspector with comments. If approved, Manager would be final
Approver. He could then add comments if any, and it would be routed to support to draft inspection letter to requester. If denied by manager, it would go back to Sr inspector for review. What would be the easiest way to set this workflow up ? Email notifications to the newly routed person are very important. I’ve been trying to play out the best workflow to accomplish this but keep hitting a wall. Any good examples out there that is similar to what I’m trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use SharePoint Workflow 2010 with SharePoint Designer. You have all actions here.